# Mapping base 64 string image to google sheet rows

Tags: image, google-apps-script, base64, pixel

I'd like a script to map base 64 png images to google sheet cells. It means to map each pixel of the png image on each cell of the sheet. It's about small images, approximatively less than 700 px and only containing simple forms. Never mind the color of the pixels, I would just want to have a 'X' result in each cell corresponding with a colored pixel in the png image.
Here's the sheet example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KmY-kPUQAt2pGYBrfkkrBlwN7qAUA7O8VpaWbC7ThOA/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

[image]

I have tried to analyse the base64 strings comparing them from diffrent images of 1 or 2 pixels, but didn't understand anything. Then I went on looking how this decoding is made in RFC but I got completely lost.

Thank you for your help

```
function getImg64(){
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('Feuille 5');
  var plage = feuille.getRange('A1:D');
  var i= 22;
  var ImgId = plage.getCell(i, 2).getValue();
  var ImgFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ImgId);
  var ImgName = ImgFile.getName();
  var ImgSize = ImgFile.getSize();
  var ImgType = ImgFile.getMimeType();
  var Img64 = Utilities.base64Encode(ImgFile.getBlob().getBytes());
  plage.getCell(i, 3).setValue(Img64);
  plage.getCell(i, 4).setValue(ImgSize);
}
```

Comment: This script by Amit Agarwal might be a good starting point: https://www.labnol.org/software/turn-images-into-pixel-art/12978/

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I haven't done anything special as I am blocked with the base 64 concept. I got lost seeing different ways of decoding the base64 strings. Then I imagine I should find which one google uses. I don't even figure how a single pixel is encoded ! I can't spend monthes on this so I'm asking here some help. My goal is to try to make a basic automatic shape recognition of plant leaves and nervations patterns from black & white scans.

Comment: So I am now looking at some simple base 64 strings and trying to find any correspondances that could make me understand what the string path is